# How to use Google ApiClient to pull Google Form and the responses (PHP)

Tags: google-apps-script

Im use this Google ApiClient https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/api/quickstart/php
To pull Form & Responses, but same the api just add script to script.google
Please show me example to get the list form and Responses

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way to get form data is to get the data from the linked sheet.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing there are no explicit REST APIs to pull Google Form data, so you won't be able to pull form responses directly from the Google API PHP client.

It you want to access form responses from PHP you'll need to use App Script to create a custom intermediary service/API that exposes the information you want.

You're already aware of the Apps Script API, so you can try creating a series of custom Apps Script functions to pull form responses and then call the Apps Script API from PHP to execute those functions to return the requisite data.

None of this is trivial to implement, and I don't have any code that I can share. But I'd start with reading the [Apps Script API documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) and work out a solution from there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67255264/how-to-use-google-apiclient-to-pull-google-form-and-the-responses-php